# KNPPaginator - Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens (Symfony2, Doctrine)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.4, knppaginator, knppaginatorbundle

I use `KNPPaginatorBundle` and I get this error message if I add a `setParameter` into a query.

I use Symfony 2.4.2, doctrine 2.2.3, knp-components 1.2.5 and KNP Paginator 2.4.0.

If I use:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
->addSelect('translation')
->leftJoin('c.translations', 'translation')
->where('c.lvl = 1');
```

it is working ok.

But if I use:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
->addSelect('translation')
->leftJoin('c.translations', 'translation')
->where('c.lvl = :lvl')
->setParameter('lvl', '1');
```

I got this error message

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match
> number of tokens.

Is this my mistake or bug in bundle or Symfony?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you are using the where clause. When using setParameter you need to use andWhere. it should look like the following:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
->addSelect('translation')
->leftJoin('c.translations', 'translation')
->andWhere('c.lvl = :lvl')
->setParameter('lvl', '1');
```